# GIMP 2.8: how to save file using detected image format

Tags: gimp

I found GIMP 2.8 has changed quite a lot, you can't just open the file, modify and save it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> anymore, instead, you must use export function, which is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>, and select a image format, is there anyway of doing the old stuff ?

Comment: Can't you use `File -> Overwrite` (Alt-F W)? You can assign that to a keyboard shortcut in `Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts`

Comment: @danielkullmann wired, `Overwrite XX` can be used only once, after that you had to use `export XX` to do the same thing

Comment: But this has an easy shortcut then: Ctrl-E.

Comment: But I agree: it is a strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was probably changed so that it *defaults* to saving the .xcf format, which retains all of Gimp's layers and whatnot.  Keeps graphic developers from saving as a .jpg which flattens all their work.

If it bothers you, go change the shortcut keys so that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> does the export function instead of the xcf save.